# how to enable standard sql for BigQuery using bq shell

Tags: google-bigquery

`bq query` has `--use_legacy_sql` flag that can be set to false to enable standard query.

How to do the same if `bq shell` is used

I tried below variations and both of those failed with error `Unknown command line flag 'use_legacy_sql'`.

```
bq --use_legacy_sql=false shell
bq shell --use_legacy_sql=false
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't look like it's possible currently, so I filed [a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=736). The alternative is to pass it to "query" each time, although that feels very verbose. For example:

```
$ bq shell
myproject> query --use_legacy_sql=false SELECT [1, 2, 3] AS arr
```